# MySQL REGEXP not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, regex

My issue is that regexp seems to not be giving the same result given the same pattern in a different context.
For example,

```
str REGEXP 'a|b|c|d|e'
//not equal to
str REGEXP 'a' OR str REGEXP 'b' OR ...
```

I perform the following query on a large data set where 'content' is text in the form of source code files. I do the inner REGEXP to search for any source files containing my list of keywords. Once I have that full list, I go through it again and check which specific keyword tripped it. This is where there is discrepancy; some files trip when checked against all keywords, but trip nothing when checked against each individual keyword.

```
select
    source_histories.id,
    MAX(source_histories.master_event_id) as master_event_id,
    source_histories.source_file_id,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break;' as break,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break ' as break_label,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]continue;' as `continue`,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]throw ' as throw,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]return;' as return_void
from
    source_histories,
    (SELECT 
        DISTINCT source_file_id
    from
        source_histories
    where
        ifnull(content, '') REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break;|[;{}[:space:]]break |[;{}[:space:]]continue;|[;{}[:space:]]throw |[;{}[:space:]]return;'
    LIMIT 100
    ) as sourceIdList
where
    source_histories.source_file_id = sourceIdList.source_file_id 
group by
    source_histories.source_file_id;
```

A section of the results that contains the issue follows. As you can see, source_file_id 92 and 95 did not match any of the keywords when checked individually, but must have matched when checked against all keywords. I have looked through their source codes, and they do contain one or more of the keywords.

```
id  master_event_id  source_file_id  break break_label  continue  throw  return_void 
256 3260             63              1     0            0         1      0
258 3640             65              1     0            0         0      0
259 3640             66              0     0            0         1      0
320 93722            85              1     0            0         0      0
346 471              92              0     0            0         0      0
360 93731            95              0     0            0         0      0
483 96052            108             1     0            0         0      0
536 1010             112             0     0            0         1      0
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what my problem may be? Is this due to a minor over sight, or a nuance of mySQL?

SOLUTION:
The issue was in the order I was analyzing my data. I was finding unique source_file_id's that matched my criteria, but there was no guarantee that the corresponding latest version of the file (max master_event_id) had the keyword(s) as-well. the following (however slow) is the solution I have found.

```
select
    source_histories.id,
    source_histories.master_event_id as master_event_id,
    source_histories.source_file_id,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break;' as break,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break ' as break_label,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]continue;' as `continue`,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]throw ' as throw,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]return;' as return_void
from
    source_histories
    inner join
        (select
            source_histories.id,
            MAX(source_histories.master_event_id) as master_event_id,
            source_histories.source_file_id
        from
            source_histories
            inner join
                (SELECT
                    DISTINCT source_file_id
                FROM
                    source_histories
                LIMIT 100
                ) as distinctSHList
            on
                source_histories.source_file_id = distinctSHList.source_file_id
            group by
                source_file_id
        ) as lastestSourceList
    on source_histories.id = lastestSourceList.id
where
    ifnull(content, '') REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break;|[;{}[:space:]]break |[;{}[:space:]]continue;|[;{}[:space:]]throw |[;{}[:space:]]return;';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `REGEX` clause, but in the way you make your selection.

The subquery will take all `source_histories` records for a given `source_file_id` into account, while the main query (due to the grouping) will take only one `source_histories` record for a given `source_file_id` into account.

To verify, remove the `GROUP BY` and `MAX` clauses from your query and join on the `source_histories.id`; the results should match.

```
select
    source_histories.id,
    source_histories.source_file_id,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break;' as break,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break ' as break_label,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]continue;' as `continue`,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]throw ' as throw,
    source_histories.content REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]return;' as return_void
from
    source_histories,
    (SELECT 
        id
    from
        source_histories
    where
        ifnull(content, '') REGEXP '[;{}[:space:]]break;|[;{}[:space:]]break |[;{}[:space:]]continue;|[;{}[:space:]]throw |[;{}[:space:]]return;'
    LIMIT 100
    ) as sourceHistoriesIdList
where
    source_histories.id = sourceHistoriesIdList.id
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that: a) the subquery will sift through all the content of source_histories for each source_file_id, and b) analyse one entry in source_histories at a time, given a corresponding source_file_id (found in the subquery). This is the desired effect of the query. From my understanding, the subquery returns a subset of entries and the main query performs a more detailed analysis, again creating a subset of a subset (so to speak). My question is, how would it be different (set or subset) if the content corresponding to each source_file_id is constant?

Comment: The subquery returns a list of `source_file_id`s that have at least one record that matches your regex. In your main query you select one record per selected `source_file_id`, but there's no guarantee that the one you select in the main query was also selected by the subquery. You only know that: 1) they have the same `source_file_id`, and 2) for that `source_file_id` there was at least one record that matched.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I removed the `group by` and `max` clause. They do not match, as you suggested, but it does show something about the data I'm working with. I will play with the query and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. They won't match. You need to join on the `source_histories.id` to make them match. I'll update my answer.

Comment: With some playing around, I found that I needed to get the max master_event_id first before I started doing regex. Thank you for your help! I will post the solution I have come up with.